# How to create a standalone database for C# project

Tags: c#, sql, database, executable

How can I create a standalone database (SQL) for my c# project? I already saved the project as an executable file but how can I create a standalone database for this to be able to run the executable file in other pc?

Comment: You can go with sql compact or sqlite.

Comment: Can I make it on SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: This will help you. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/811432/Use-Local-DataBase-file-sdf-in-Windows-Application

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite should be probably an easy and light solution. There exists an assembly for .net: https://system.data.sqlite.org . I think it is also available as nuGet package.
Hope this help!